# How to invite friends in Facebook app with AS3

Tags: facebook, flash, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

i'm making a Facebook application (Flash) where i must invite friends. Every place i reach i found this piece of code but isn't working for me because result.request_ids is null. I need to know how many friends the user invited!!! Please help!!!

Code:

```
private function inviteFriends():void{
var dat:Object = new Object();
dat.message = "Let's invite friends for our Super Extra Max Facebook App, more info go to http://blog.ukasz.com";
dat.title   = 'Super Extra Max Facebook App';
// filtering for non app users only
dat.filters = ['app_non_users'];
//You can use these two options for diasplaying friends invitation window 'iframe' 'popup'
Facebook.ui('apprequests', dat, onUICallback, 'popup');
```

}

```
private function onUICallback(result:Object):void{
if(result == null){
     trace('User closed the pop up window without inviting any friends');
     return
}
var invitedUsers:Array  = new Array();
invitedUsers = result.request_ids as Array;
trace('You Have Invited ', invitedUsers.length,' friends');
//Simple if else if you want user to invite certain amount of friends
if(invitedUsers.length > 1){
    trace('GREAT, USER IS GENERATING TRAFFIC');
}else{
    trace('No Good, User invited only one friend.');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
function invite(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var obj:Object = 
        {
            message: "",
            title: ""
        };
        Facebook.ui("apprequests", obj, cbi, "iframe");
    }

function cbi(res):void
    { 
        field_txt.appendText(res.request_ids);
    }
```

Comment: The solution was to change "result.request_ids" for "result.to". Facebook changed it.

Comment: @JoaquínFernández, you can post your own answer if you have resolved this issue :)